# Uploading multiple files in a ModelForm

Tags: jquery, django, file-upload

I have a simple model in Django:

```
class Test(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=180, unique=True)
    file1 = models.FileField(upload_to=download_loc)
    preview = models.FileField(upload_to=preview_loc)
```

file1 is a file, and I generate dynamically on the client-side a "preview" of file1 (jpg image).

I am trying to upload the two of them on the same form, but I cannot find a simple way to do this.
How could I do that with Jquery?

This is the class for the form I have:

```
class TestForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Test
        fields = ('title', 'file1') # I don't want to put preview here because it should be done without the user intervention (I don't want the user to see a button with choose file for the preview)
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to intergrate thumbnail generation to the model level, use the `django-imagekit` https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-imagekit

Example:

```
from django.db import models
from imagekit.models import ImageSpecField
from imagekit.processors import ResizeToFill

class Profile(models.Model):
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars')
    avatar_thumbnail = ImageSpecField(source='avatar',
                                      processors=[ResizeToFill(100, 50)],
                                      format='JPEG',
                                      options={'quality': 60})

profile = Profile.objects.all()[0]
print profile.avatar_thumbnail.url    # > /media/CACHE/images/982d5af84cddddfd0fbf70892b4431e4.jpg
print profile.avatar_thumbnail.width  # > 100
```

Although, in most of the cases you shouldn't be adding the preview to the model, since there are a lot of packages for generating thumbnails on the fly (on the template level) in Django:

- `easy-thumbnail` http://easy-thumbnails.readthedocs.org/en/2.1/usage/#templates
- `sorl-thumbnail` http://sorl-thumbnail.readthedocs.org/en/latest/template.html#thumbnail